# Вызов диалогового Activity без Action Bar

Tags: android-sdk, android, activity

Как вызвать диалоговое Activity без Action Bar. Я знаю как вызывать диалоговое Activity или убирать у Activity Action Bar, но как это объединить? P.S. Или, может быть, есть аналог с фрагментами?

Comment: Да, есть DialogFragment (ссылка на доки: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как у него выключить Action Bar?